# Close C Files without Calling Exit() from iOS Application

Tags: c, swift, xcode, exit

I have an iOS application and a portion of my app is in C which uses files for reading and writing. The issue is that my C code needs to be run multiple times from 1 app launch and on the second and on attempts to run the C code the files used for reading and writing run into issues because they are not properly closed.

I suspect this is because to close my C code I just `return 1` to resume execution of my iOS app when the C code is finished executing. However I have noticed that by calling `exit(0)` after the C code finishes executing the files do behave as expected. But the issue is that calling `exit(0)` stops execution of my iOS app.

So my question is:
-Is there some equivalent to `exit(0)` that will cause my C code to stop executing but my iOS application continues running, or what is `exit(0)` doing related to file closing/exiting that I can just add to my C code instead of calling `exit(0)`?

Comment: Do you close the files?

Comment: Is the `C` code a separate process from the Swift code? Or code in the same process?  Doing something like `exit` would only make sense if it's a separate process.   In either case, the thing to do is have the C code clean up its own mess (ie close it's own files).  How you go about having Swift tell the C code to do that is to depends on whether they are in the same process or not, and if they are, how you already communicate between them.

Comment: Yes the C code is a separate process from the Swift code, it is basically a calculator that is called from Swift so I need to have it run multiple times not just once. What is weird is the first time the C code runs everything works fine, it is just the 2nd time and on where the C code does not work as expected and the files with the results from the C code are not written to but the first time the C code runs they are written to

Comment: If code you don't own and therefore shouldn't change, you could use a signal to terminate it.  That means you'll need to relaunch it to use its services again.  If you can inspect its sources, you can look to see if it supports `SIGHUP` signals which a lot of servers use support resetting without killing them.   Looks for calls to `signal()` in the C sources, probably in `main`.  Or it's documentation may list them

Comment: `man signal` will tell you more about signals.  In the worst case, if you have its process id, you can `import Darwin` and  call `kill(pid, SIGKILL)`.  If supports `SIGHUP` then you can pass that instead of `SIGKILL` and then you probably won't have to relaunch it.

Comment: You may have an issue with the files not being deleted rather than not being closed.   That's a different issue.  If you know their name or can get them by iterating through a directory, you can delete them from Swift using `FileManager`.

Comment: @ChipJarred Thanks for the suggestions! The reason I suspect it is an issue with the files not being closed is before my C code runs I delete the files if they exist and then copy over "blank" files from the bundle to the documents directory that the C code needs. Then when the C code runs it should write to these files. First time it runs is no problem, second time nothing gets written to them and there are no C errors or anything indicating an issue.

Comment: ..or call `unlink()` from the C code using the same filename used to `open()` or `fopen()`... Do that *after* closing the file though.

Comment: I'd need to see how you're starting the process, but I do wonder why a calculator is writing files at all.   I would think a pipe, or unix domain socket would make more sense.. or use XPC.

Comment: @ez4nick As someone else mentioned `return code;` from main is equivalent to `exit(code);` Well it is in C.  If it's actually C++ some destructors won't get called.  But either way Darwin *will* flush all of its open file buffers, and close the files.  So as long as the C code terminates, any files it opened are closed.   That's not the case for any file descriptors it inherits from the parent process.  If Swift is keeping the files open, especially if open for writing/appending, then that would prevent C from writing.

Comment: You say that you aren't getting errors from C, but how are you checking them?  Functions like `fwrite`, `fputs`, `fprintf` return the number of bytes written, not an error code.  You have to check if they return the same number of bytes you attempted to write, and use `errno` or call `ferror()` to get the actual error code.  `write` (not `fwrite`) will return -1 to indicate an error, and again you check `errno` to get the specific error code.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference between calling `exit` and a `return` from `main`.

> **5.1.2.2.3    Program termination**
> **1** If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a `return` from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the main function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of `0`. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

Comment: Does this also hold if the `return` is from a non main function?

Comment: You can only end the program with a `return` that is in `main`. The `exit` function can be called from anywhere, as an alternative to dropping back thru the call stack to `main`. Both operations flush and close open files. **7.22.4.4** The `exit` function ... **4** Next, all open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, all open streams are closed, and all files created by the `tmpfile` function are removed.

Comment: I think my issue is the "Next, all open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, all open streams are closed, and all files created by the tmpfile function are removed" portion. I am calling `return` not from `main` so I don't think all the file cleanup needed from `return/exit` is happening. I tried `fflush(stdout);` before my `return` but that didn't seem to fix it either.